# How to play audio files one at a time, only when clicked

Tags: jquery, audio

I have multiple audio tags throughout my page, all with the same class and different ids, that I want to be able to play only when that button is clicked. So far, the code works for only the first clip because jquery needs to have the index to work for the audio tag. To play each I would have to use their ids and write separate code for each one. Is there a drier way to do this?

```
$(".audio-container").on("click", function (){
    var sound = $(".clips")[0];
    if (sound.paused == false) {
        sound.pause();
    } else {
        sound.play();
    } })
```

How can I tell jquery to grab the ids and for each one play when clicked?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is my html. My clips are in divs throughout the page, not all in one container.

```
  <div class="audio-container">
    <audio class="clips" id="sound1" src="audio/source.mp3"></audio>
  </div>

  <div class="audio-container">
    <audio class="clips" id="sound2" src="audio/source.mp3"></audio>
  </div>
```

Comment: Post your html plz

Comment: can you provide you html structure please..if your html structure is in ul>li format i guess you can do this by getting the eq of li based on click.

Comment: I included the html